# With high probability analysis

Tags: expected-value, randomized-algorithms

I am quite confused with 'with high probability analysis' in randomized algorithms. Perhaps it's helpful to illustrate with an example. What is the expected number of rounds to have at least one head during coin flips with high probability? I think with high probability is essentially to have a probability of $$1-\frac{1}{n}$$  so with large n it converges to 1. Is it O(log n)? If so, why?

Comment: In $n$ tosses the probability of all T's is $(1/2)^n,$ so probability of at least one H in $n$ tosses is $1-(1/2)^n.$ // Not clear exactly what to make of your attempt to specify 'high probability'.

Comment: Are you suggesing that the probability of head changes as we toss, wrt $n$?